# How can I dynamically update raster visualization in python?

Tags: python, raster, visualisation, dynamic

I want to visualize a very large raster image with python in an efficient way.

I have looked into datashader and found out that it is possible to dynamically update plots with millions of data points based on the current view and zoom level.

I was wondering if there is a way to visualize raster images in a similar way. It would be nice to have the raster at a lower resolution zoomed out and  a more detailed view zoomed in.

So far I have seen this behavior in Qgis but I am not sure how to achieve something similar with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to setup a lightweight tile server with [Terracotta](https://github.com/DHI-GRAS/terracotta) and then view the imagery via the XYZ-layer endpoint with either folium (custom [tilelayers](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/TilesExample.ipynb#Custom-tiles)) or bokeh ([WMTSTileSource](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tiles.html?highlight=wmtstilesource#bokeh.models.tiles.WMTSTileSource), there is an example in the Geographic Plots [tutorial notebook](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/master?filepath=tutorial%2F00%20-%20Introduction%20and%20Setup.ipynb).)